# C-panel not sending Laravel mail

Tags: laravel, cpanel, webmail

So I currently have setup my laravel project in C-panel, and have updated the .env file to have the appropriate email address.  When I, for instance, use the make:auth reset password feature it responds with the appropriate "We have e-mailed your password reset link!", but there is no mail sent.

I am not sure how to test this to find the hole in the problem.  When I used mailtrap I was able to send and receive emails no problem, but there is some issue with the webmail in c-panel not processing and sending out an email from Laravel 5.4

Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `.env` file. set `MAIL_DRIVER=mail` it will start working. make sure you set `from` in `mail.php`
`

Answer (score 0):

Some Hosting provider block `smtp` to force to use cPanel Webmail, You can try `sendmail` for cPanel in `.env` file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

**Note** :

- Check email configuration: Make sure that the email configuration settings in your .env file are correct. Double-check the SMTP host, port, username, and password.
- Check firewall: If your server has a firewall, make sure that the ports used for SMTP (usually ports 25, 465, or 587) are open.
- Check spam folder: Sometimes emails may be filtered as spam by the recipient's email service. Check the spam folder to see if the email has been delivered there.
- Check logs: Check the Laravel log files located in storage/logs for any error messages related to email sending. This can give you a clue as to what the problem may be.
- Check email quota: If you are using cPanel email accounts, check the email account quota. If the quota has been exceeded, email sending may be blocked.